# Capybara + Selenium-webdriver use different browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to make a each loop that use different Capybara drivers, each of with a different browser.

```
require 'spec_helper'

browsers = ['chrome','firefox','safari']

browsers.each  do |browser|

 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :"#{browser}")
 end

 describe 'Home', :js => true do
  it 'Welcome' do
   visit '/home'
   page.should have_content('Welcome.')
  end
 end
end
```

But Capybara always opens on browser and I don't understand why.

Comment: This test is probably unnecessary.  If your app displays content in one browser, it will display in them all.  The only difference will be in how it is styled, which is difficult to automate tests for anyhow. Capybara isn't rigged to navigate in multiple browsers because it's not very useful to begin with.

Comment: What do you mean by "opens on browser"